# training word2vec from a webinar subtitles

Tags: nlp, word2vec, doc2vec

I am building a model to start playback of video from a time frame , depending on the context. For example play climax of the movie, starts playing from 59th minute.

I am using subtitles of the video, and match the text in the particular sequence and identify the time frame. I am trying find exact words with real expressions $$not so effective$$. I came across word2vec which can find simialar words with cosine similarities

Comment: Yes, word2vec can help with fuzzy word-matching. But what is the question?

Comment: I have a lecture on python. I want to pull where decorators is discussed in the video, by just saying what are decorators?

Comment: You should show examples of the target texts, and queries, to make it clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please post examples of the webinar titles and search terms to get a better answer but based on what you have posted. You do not necessarily have to train a new word2vec model if you are using a language like English with several pre-trained vectors already available. Here are the steps:

1) Calculate the vector for your search term using pre-trained word2vec vectors.

2) Calculate the vector for each subtitle and store in a suitable list

3) Use cosine_similarity function from a ML library to calculate similarity between the vector from step 1 and each of the vectors in the list from step 2.

4) The subtitle with the similarity score closest to 1 is what you are seeking and you can reverse look-up the associated time for that frame

Comment: yeah this purely depends on the pre-trained vectors and its corpus. I am in situation :higher cosine similarity for subtitle texts that don't exactly represent the content